# How to start several writeable instances of a singularity image

Tags: singularity-container

I created a Docker image based on an existing e-mail server image. When I start an instance of the image some configuration files are written by an entrypoint script. After that a program of mine starts doing some performance tests and writing the results in a file. I only need to preserve this file and thus created a volume for it. The other files do not need to be stored.

Now I want to make a singularity container out of this. My problem is that there is an error during the starting process since the configuration files can not be written as the file system is read-only by default. I understand that I could use `--sandbox` while building and `--writeable` while runnung. This however creates exactly one container and I am not able to run several of these containers in paralell. Is there a way of getting a non-persistent, writable filesystem in the container? If so how can I still save my result file?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the files created, you can use the [`--writable-tmpfs`](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.8/user-guide/persistent_overlays.html?highlight=--writable-tmpfs#overview) flag. This can be used with read-only images as well sandboxes.

If there are any files created that you want to persist, make sure to copy them to a locally mounted location before the singularity process finishes.